# PDFBox : add multiple signatures

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I am trying to create a workflow in which a single document is signed twice in a row by two different recipients, keeping all the signatures valid at the end.

This is what I did:

- from a clean pdf file, I add two PDSignatureField to the first page of the document, each named according to the recipient name
- I then add an annotation (with PDFTron viewer) on the first signature field.
- I digitally sign the document for the first signature and add DocMDP permissions :

  ```
    if (document.getVersion() >= 1.5f && accessPermissions == 0) {
        SigUtils.setMDPPermission(document, signature, 2);
    }
  ```
- everything is fine here, the document is signed and valid
- I then add another annotation to the second signature field and save the doc
- From this point, the previous signature is invalid, although I did add some permissions on signature fields to the document.

Could anybody help me out on this ? =)

Comment: You need to do two passes. I.e. sign the first, save incremental, then repeat.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Actually, I already do the save incremental for each signature. It works fine if I don't add any annotation in between both signatures (ie: The first and second signatures are both valid) My goal is to set the annotation associated to the second signature field as "not impacting" the first signature validation. Do you know if it is possible ?

Comment: I'm confused, a signature has only 1 annotation and it's not added as a separate step (value 2 means "Permitted changes shall be filling in forms, instantiating page templates, and signing; other changes shall invalidate the signature" so only adding an annotation wouldn't work). The best is to start with the examples, get it to build/work and then start to modify.

Comment: The thing is that the annotation is added by an external tool which is not PDFBox. If I understand you correctly, there is no way to tell the signature field "every annotation that comes upon you will be ignored during signature validation process".... My goal would then to be able to retrieve the annotation within the new document,  and recreate it inside PDFBox in the original document, and save it incrementally with signature... Am I correct ? :)

Comment: See in the PDF specification, look for "Entries in the DocMDP transform parameters dictionary", there is no fine tuned setting like that. Yes it might be possible to get the annotation from an external PDF. I'd use the CreateVisualSignature2.java example and replace `createVisualSignatureTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The example in CreateVisibleSignature2 can add an annotation  to a signature field (if I am correct). How would you proceed to extract the annotation associated to the signature field in the other PDF ? Is there a feature in PDFBox that allows this ? Thank you!

Comment: PDPage.getAnnotation() and then find out which one is yours.

Comment: Please share both example PDFs illustrating the issue and some actual code. But as @Tilman already said, certification level 2 does not allow for adding new annotations.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I think my goal is not reachable as I would like to add an annotation from an external tool to the PDF without breaking the signature validation. Which is not possible according to PDF standard specification (the annotation needs to be added with PDFBox as an incremental save)